# Data from Firebase not automatically loading Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

I have tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and all the other solutions I could find online but my data from firebase does not automatically load and I need to click a edit text box to load the data. Please can someone guide me on how I can solve this. Thanks.

My Adapter is looks like:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
        this.c = c;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final  Spacecraft s=spacecrafts.get(position);
        holder.nameTxt.setText(s.getName());
        holder.propTxt.setText(s.getPropellant());
        holder.descTxt.setText(s.getDescription());
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int pos) {
                //OPEN DETAI ACTIVITY
                openDetailActivity(s.getName(),s.getDescription(),s.getPropellant());
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }
    //OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
    private void openDetailActivity(String...details)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(c,DetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NAME_KEY",details[0]);
        i.putExtra("DESC_KEY",details[1]);
        i.putExtra("PROP_KEY",details[2]);
        c.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

This is how I am reading data from firebase

```
public class FirebaseHelper {
    DatabaseReference db;
    Boolean saved=null;
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts=new ArrayList<>();
    public FirebaseHelper(DatabaseReference db) {
        this.db = db;
    }
    //WRITE IF NOT NULL
    public Boolean save(Spacecraft spacecraft)
    {
        if(spacecraft==null)
        {
            saved=false;
        }else
        {
            try
            {
                db.child("Spacecraft").push().setValue(spacecraft);
                saved=true;
            }catch (DatabaseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved=false;
            }
        }
        return saved;
    }
    //IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        spacecrafts.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Spacecraft spacecraft=ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);
            spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);
        }
    }
    //READ THEN RETURN ARRAYLIST
    public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve() {
        db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return spacecrafts;
    }
}
```

In my mainactivity I am setting the adpater like this:

```
db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper(db);
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), FirebaseHelper.retrieve());
adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
recycler.setAdapter(adapter );
adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I have tried placing the **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** in many places and classes but not luck. Any help will be nice as this is really pushing me back and has been bugging me for a while now. Thanks and let me know if I can provide any more code.

Comment: Does the recyclerView have a LayoutManager?

Comment: Do **not** repost questions to gain attention. I've undeleted your previous copy of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading data in Firebase is asynchronous. So technically, you're returning `spacecrafts` while it is still empty (because the data reading is still happening asynchronously). I suggest you take a look at [FirebaseUI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) as it can easily help you synchronize your data with your RecyclerView.